# Convert html string with anchor tags into plain text in freemarker

Tags: freemarker

Is there a way in freemarker to convert the below html string into plain-text?

**Challange:**  data assign in below tag is dynamic including links and their placement.

```
<#assign data = '<li>List item 1 with <a href="https://some-link.com">some link</a></li><li>List item 2 with <a href="https://some-link1.com">some link1</a> and <a href="https://some-link2.com">some link2</a></li>' />
```

**Expected: Need data in plain text format like below:**

```
- List item 1 with some link <https://some-link.com>
- List item 2 with some link1 <https://some-link1.com> and some link2 <https://some-link2.com>
```

What I have achieved till now:

I am able to remove the complete html code using regex freemarker but it also removes the anchor tag urls which cause unexpected results.

```
${data?replace("<[^>]*>", "", "r")}

// result
- List item 1 with some link
- List item 2 with some link1 and some link2
```

Any help would really appreciate!!

Comment: From where you are, it's easy to go one step further and remove `li` tags only. Then `a` tags the way you wanted. But then question is, what other HTML elements do you need to handle and how? A generic HTML to plain text converted would be very complex of course, so where do you draw the line? Also because of entity references, etc., a robust parser is not something that you should implement inside the template.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the solution below.

```
<#function htmlListToPlainText param>
<#assign str = param?replace('<ol>','')?replace('</ol>','')?split('</li>')/>
<#assign result>
<#list str as item>
<#if item?contains('<a')>
<#assign anchors = item?matches(r"href='(.*?)'") />
<#if anchors?size == 0>
<#assign anchors = item?matches(r'href="(.*?)"') />
</#if>
<#assign mitem = item?replace('</a>','[0]','f')?replace('</a>','[1]','f')?replace('</a>','[2]','f')?replace("<[^>]*>", "", "r") />
<#list anchors as m>
<#assign mitem = mitem?replace('[${m?index}]',' <${m?groups[1]}>','f') />
</#list>
-${mitem}
<#elseif item?has_next>
-${item?replace("<[^>]*>", "", "r")}
</#if>
</#list>
</#assign>
<#return result>
</#function>
```

**How to Use**

```
${htmlListToPlainText(YoursignalName)}
```

**Limitation:**

- Handling upto 3 dynamic links in one `<li>` tag.